# Kotlin — как подключить anko

Tags: android, kotlin

Товарищи, помогите, пожалуйста, понять и решить вопрос.

AndroidStudio

MainActivity.kt:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import org.jetbrains.anko.doAsync <---

...

doAsync <---
```

build.gradle:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.9"
```

Строчка doAsync и слово anko подсвечены красным и Problems пишет:

```
Uresolved reference: anko
Uresolved reference: doAsync
```

Что делать, как решить?

Comment: `gradle build` что говорит? Вообще Anko уже с нами распрощался: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md

Comment: Видимо, вот это говорит: Unresolved reference: anko

И я так понял, что надо что-то вместо anko. Спасибо!

Comment: Похоже версию 0.9 удалили с JCenter, поэтому и не ресолвится: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.anko/anko-common?repo=jcenter

Comment: 0.10.8 выдаёт такую же картину