# Не работает библиотека anko в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Пытаясь подключить библиотеку в build gradle выдаёт ошибку при синхронизации
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.8"
Как решить её и пожалуйста объясните более понятным способом

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ну прочитай ошибку, она ведь не просто так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно комментам [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380131/kotlin-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-anko) anko пару лет как мертва, в т.ч. удалена из публичного репозитория и её использовать просто не получится. Если вам обязательно нужно кодом UI делать - посмотрите в сторону [Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose)

Comment: Мне просто из anko нужны модули doAsync{} и UIthread{}

Comment: Такие штуки, скорее всего, вам надо из Kotlin coroutines брать. Вообще, простого способа переключения потоков нет, библиотеки тут не помогут